# Cannot find the declaration of element 'android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have created an xml file called `activity_main(sw50dp)`, but when I try to validate it, it gives me the errors:

> Error:(4, 42) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout'.

and

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea.jar!\standardSchemas\xhtml1.dtd

Error:(26, 3) The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
```

activity_main file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/images"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDiv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="320dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:text="÷"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="320dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:text="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonReset"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="320dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:text="C"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textNum"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main(sw50dp) file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

I have created other layout files as well for example activity_main(normal-land). I didn't have any problems with them.

Comment: Update your question with .xml... Also you should have "default" layout as well, that is outside sw50dp directory.

Comment: The syntax of your last TextView and Button is incorrect in activity_main. They need a closing tag.

Comment: Also, "activity_main(sw50dp)" is not well formed. It should end with "/>". Is that the entire file?

Comment: No, it's not. I had to deleted some codes, because when i tried to post it, it gave me an error :   it looks like your post is mostly code ... something like that.

Comment: If you can put the project on github or similar, I'll download it and see what is wrong...

Comment: It builds and runs without any changes: Android Studio 3.1.2. It might be worth doing help -> "Check for Updates" and fully upgrade the environment then do a File -> "Close Project" followed by a File -> "Open Project". Else try options like: File -> "Invalidate Caches & Restart", Build -> "Clean Project", Build -> "Rebuild Project".

Comment: I tried all of these, bu still the same. Everytime i create a layout like activity_main(sw560dp) or activity_main(1080x1920), it gives me an error and doesn't build.

Comment: The project that you put on Google drive does not have a "sw560dp" directory. I created one called "layout-sw560dp" and copied the activity_mail.xml file from "layout" to "layout-sw560dp", but again it builds fine.

Comment: Also, just to be sure, it must be "layout-" *not* "layout_"

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error messages using the incorrect name "layout_sw560dp" instead of the correct name "layout-sw560dp"

Comment: My problem fixed. i typed layout name by keyboard not choosed "smallest screen width" from dropdown list (available qualifiers). So much thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. I added the directory creation procedure to the answer. If you think that it contains enough info to help people with a similar problem then please accept the answer by pressing the up arrow. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This error can happen if the resource directory name is incorrect.

Best procedure for creating the directory name:

1. Doing: File -> New -> Android Resource Directory
2. Choose: Smallest Screen Width
3. Tap ">>" and enter [The number of dips]

Also, adding this line to the Gradle file solves similar errors:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
}
```

Followed by a resync.

[Constraint Layout Versions](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/constraint/group-index.xml)

[Google Constraint Layout Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples/archive/master.zip)

[image: Project Downloaded from Google Drive]

[image: Project Modified Layout Directory]

Comment: current stable version is '1.1.0'

Comment: Oops. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: Best to post the XML...Added link to the Google ConstraintLayout samples. I just built them in AS 3.1.1. They all run fine.

Answer (score 0):

for cases like this you can add the line

tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource"

to the xml code of the layout files you have inside the layout directory and it should ignore the errors generated because of missing resource that's not necessary to run the app