# Android Studio 4.1.2 resource errors when validating layout

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to build my first app in Android Studio 4.1.2. I have created a new project (Empty project) with default "Hello world!" Main Activity.

When trying to validate the activity_main.xml I get the following errors:

- Error:External resource http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android is not registered C:\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
- Error:(7, 35) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout'.
- Error:Premature end of file.

I have already tried the following:

- Reinstall Android studio
- Sync Project with Gradle Files
- Invalidate Caches / Restart

build.gradle also has the line implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

I can run the application in emulator or actual device but apparently the validation error prevents me to refer to the layout elements from Kotlin code.

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Here's the activity_main.xml in code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textMyText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: have you try to resycn project with gradle?

Comment: Yes. No help from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find the declaration of element 'android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063467/cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-android-support-constraint-constraintlay)

Answer (score 0):

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Change this to
```

> ```
> RelativeLayout
> ```

Comment: Still getting the same errors, only now the ConstraintLayout replaced with RelativeLayout: